# notation question Hessian on compact Kahler manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

On a compact Kahler manifold, what does the notation $\nabla \bar{\nabla} u$ for a smooth function $u$ stands for?

Comment: The complex hessian?

Comment: I see. So what about the notation $|\bar{\nabla} \bar{\nabla} u|$?

Comment: Of course, you should see how your source defined its notation. I would assume this is the $2$-tensor $\sum \dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial\bar z^j\partial\bar z^k}d\bar z^j\otimes d\bar z^k$.

Comment: The reference I was looking at did not define it. I will try to use this definition and see if it works out.